# Select records in date range using Yesod.Persist

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod

I need to select all records in a table where a columns date is between 2 dates, before a date or after a date.

I can see the [`selectList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-0.9.0.4/docs/Database-Persist.html#v:selectList) function takes a parameter [`Filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-0.9.0.4/docs/Database-Persist.html#t:Filter) which seems to be what I would need to select records by a date range but I can't work out what I would need to put in the filter parameter to select by a range or before and after a date.

Comment: Can you add a simplified DB schema, along with a minified working example (with Stack interpreter if possible) ?

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out you can get the records before and after a date by adding a filter

`[TableDateColumn <=. UTCTime]`

To get the records with a date before now you can use

```
getBeforeDate = do
    now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
    selectList [TableDateColumn <=. Just now] []
```

I haven't verified this yet but as `selectList` takes a list of filters it would make sense for selecting between a range to be

```
selectList [TableDateColumn >=. timeStart, TableDateColumn <=. timeEnd] []
```